# IOAPIC[0] not in IVRS table

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I have a fresh Ubuntu install from USB. When I boot the PC it takes me straight to GNU Grub, when I select Ubuntu I get the following messages.

```
[Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[0] not in IVRS table
[Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
```

I can get to the Ubuntu desktop via "Advanced options for Ubuntu" > "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-30-generic (recovery mode)" > "resume" but the CPU runs at nearly 100% and is not sustinable.

PC Specs:

- AMD A6-6400K
- MSI A68HI ​Mini ITX F​M2+ Mother​board

Comment: Updating the firmware didn't work for me. Anyone have any other solutions?

Comment: @outisnihil You can use `ivrs_ioapic` kernel option to fix IVRS table. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 15):

The reason the CPU is all the time 100% used I think it is different than the message you are seeing.

**About the error message**

Now about `AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[0] not in IVRS table` and `AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found in IVRS table`errors. Those messages mean that your CMOS/BIOS setup is configured to enable [IOMMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_memory_management_unit), but BIOS lacks IVRS table that is describing which is the address of IOMMU and SMBus Controller. IVRS = I/O Virtualization Reporting Structure. See also: http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/48882_IOMMU.pdf

**What is IOMMU?**

[IOMMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_memory_management_unit) is a hardware unit that today is part of CPU. It allows to map device-visible virtual addresses to physical addresses.

**Why IOMMU?**

1. IOMMU allows to have better security and protect your computer from some attacks from someone having access to some busses like PCIe and firewire.
2. you can expose a physical PCIe device to a VM (PCI passthrough).
3. it is required for [SR-IOV (VNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-root_input/output_virtualization)

**Fixing "AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[0] not in IVRS table"**

1. Update motherboard firmware

The proper fix should come from hardware manufacturer of the motherboard. So if you have a BIOS/firmware update for your motherboard, install it as this might fix the problem. Unfortunately for my motherboard (Asus Crosshair V Formula) the IVRS is broken even in the latest BIOS/firmware update (version 1703, Release Date: 10/17/2012).

2. Linux workarround

If the manufacturer of the MB is not offering a fix, you can fix this in Linux by specifying in the kernel startup parameters where those devices are located using `ivrs_ioapic` option.

Here are the steps to do it. For more details see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254677

Boot your kernel by adding `amd_iommu_dump=1` to the kernel options. You can do this via grub menu during boot.

In the kernel log, you will see some lines like:

```
$ dmesg |grep 'DEV_SPECIAL(IOAPIC\|not in IVRS table'
[    0.133756] AMD-Vi:   DEV_SPECIAL(IOAPIC[0])     devid: 00:14.0
[    0.133995] AMD-Vi:   DEV_SPECIAL(IOAPIC[255])       devid: 00:00.1
[    0.134116] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
[    0.134235] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[6] not in IVRS table
$
```

Write down the indexes from `IOAPIC`. In this case those are `5` and `6`. Note  the devid, where `00:14.0` is ok and `00:00.1` is incorrect.

Search for the bus address for those devices and write down the addresses (`00:00.2` and `00:14.0`)

```
$ lspci -nn | egrep "SMBus | IOMMU"
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890S/RD990 I/O Memory Management Unit (IOMMU) [1002:5a23]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385] (rev 42)
$
```

Now add as kernel parameters: `ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[6]=00:00.2` where index `5` and `6` were found in dmesg output and the values are from lspci output. You can make this permanent by editing `/etc/default/grub` file, then running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

3. Disable IOMMU in UEFI/BIOS configuration

Disabling IOMMU has a small performance benefit. But it is undesirable to disable it for security and stability of the system. IOMMU is required for certain virtualization setups (PCI pass-through, SR-IOV) and disabling it is not an option.

Comment: The option 2 seems to fix that specific issue (i.e. no more error messages). However, X can't start anymore :) I'm on a Lenovo Ideapad 320 AMD A12 and Radeon R7

Comment: What is the error reported by Wayland or X11? Maybe you could post a new question with it.

Comment: Surprisingly enough no real errors from Xorg. However, the screen stays black (I can see the "_" in top-left corner) and I see those kind of errors coming from the kernel `kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU`

Comment: Following your suggestion, I've posted a new question with more details https://superuser.com/questions/1602030/amd-vi-firmware-bug-ioapic5-not-in-ivrs-table

Answer (score 3):

I updated the firmware of my motherboard and this has appeared to have fixed it.