# Dual Booting Linux: error IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 7375 with the latest BIOS firmware and with the latest version of Windows.

I have a USB stick that was flashed with the 18.04.3 Ubuntu disk image file using [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to a 15 GB unallocated partition, but every time I boot the Ubuntu stick and press *Install Ubuntu* these errors come up on the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahG0I.jpg).

```
[    0.085945] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
[    0.085948] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table 
[    0.085949] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : No southbridge IOAPIC found
[    0.085951] AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
[    0.158777] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0], AE
_NOT FOUND (20181213/dswload2-160) 
[    0.158788] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/ps
object-221) 
[    8.366067] AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
[   32.129183] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 22s! [swapper/4:0]
[   36.117183] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [migration/0:11]
[   36.121184] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [migration/1:17]
[   36.125183] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [migration/3:29]
[   36.125185] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [migration/2:23]
[   36.129187] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 22s! [migration/5:41]
[   36.133183] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 22s! [migration/6:47]
[   36.137184] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s! [migration/7:53] 
_
```

I've tried to update my BIOS to fix the issue. Is there something I'm missing?

Update: I've been able to get to the ubuntu screen with the four dots by configuring the install with ACPI = off, but then it freezes.

Comment: Does it work if you put  `acpi=off` as a kernel parameter?  See [How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/a/160056).  See this question too : [IOAPIC 0 not in IVRS table](https://superuser.com/a/1255206/269373)

Comment: I've tried putting ACPI = off and it gets to the ubuntu screen with four dots then freezes up. I'm not sure how to find the values that I need to assign to the tables that are not coming up without having access to the kernel.