# AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table

Tags: linux, debian, lenovo-laptop, kernel

Booting Debian bullseye `5.9.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.1-1 (2020-10-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux` on my Lenovo Ideapad 320 (lastest available BIOS) I get those firmware bug complaining about missing IOAPIC entries in the IVRS table.

Please note the following verbose output comes from `amd_iommu_dump=1` as suggested in [this similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1255206/1041136)

```
[    0.242293] AMD-Vi: Using IVHD type 0x11
[    0.243158] AMD-Vi: device: 00:00.2 cap: 0040 seg: 0 flags: b8 info 0000
[    0.243159] AMD-Vi:        mmio-addr: 00000000feb80000
[    0.243184] AMD-Vi:   DEV_SELECT_RANGE_START  devid: 00:01.0 flags: 00
[    0.243186] AMD-Vi:   DEV_RANGE_END           devid: ff:1f.6
[    0.243857] AMD-Vi:   DEV_ALIAS_RANGE                 devid: ff:00.0 flags: 00 devid_to: 00:14.4
[    0.243858] AMD-Vi:   DEV_RANGE_END           devid: ff:1f.7
[    0.243863] AMD-Vi:   DEV_SPECIAL(HPET[0])           devid: 00:14.0
[    0.243904] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
[    0.243910] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
[    0.243912] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : No southbridge IOAPIC found
[    0.243913] AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
```

Here are the devices of interest:

```
$ lspci -nn | egrep "SMBus | IOMMU"

00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit [1022:1577]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 4a)
```

Now, booting the system adding `ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:02.0` to the kernel cmdline seems to work until X tries to start up. The screen remains black (only the static cursor stays visible in the top-corner of the screen) and in the kernel messages like these:

```
$ journalctl -p err -b -1

kernel: pci 0000:00:14.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0xfdf800ff98 flags=0x0008]
kernel: kfd kfd: TOPAZ  not supported in kfd
kernel: iommu ivhd0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST device=00:00.1 pasid=0x00000 address=0xfdf8160020 flags>
kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
kernel: rcu:         3-....: (20999 ticks this GP) idle=d6e/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=5416/5416 fqs=5246 
kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_sched detected expedited stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 3-... } 21442 jiffies s: 125 root: 0x8/.
kernel: rcu: blocking rcu_node structures:
kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [pipewire-media-:993]
kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [pipewire-media-:993]
kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
kernel: rcu:         3-....: (84002 ticks this GP) idle=d6e/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=5416/5416 fqs=20988 
kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_sched detected expedited stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 3-... } 87490 jiffies s: 125 root: 0x8/.
kernel: rcu: blocking rcu_node structures:
```

I have also tried to recompile the kernel with VGA_SWITCHEROO=N as suggested in [this kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200087#c14), but no changes.

I've also noticed that the offending param seems to be `ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:02.0`. In fact, if I boot the system only with `ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0` the firmware bug message disappears and the desktop boots as expected.

Comment: Do you have access to ssh after starting X11? Is it X11 or Wayland? Try to boot with `iommu=soft`

Comment: Contact also the manufacturer (Lenovo). This is a firmware bug that they should fix.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the laptop boots and seems to work even with those `Firmware bug` messages. However, I guess some features offered by AMD-Vi might not be available.

Comment: At the end I decided to simply disable interrupt remapping and get rid of those errors `intremap=off`.

Comment: Do you use IOMMU (e.g. for PCI-passthrough, SR-IOV or security reasons?) If not you can disable it in BIOS or in kernel cmd line at boot time with grub.