# Ubuntu Installation fails due to "inittramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, kernel

**Problem Descripton (Solution below)**

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 (I tried different OS as well, leading to the same problem) on a fresh hard drive and I keep running in the same problem. The installation (or even the "try Ubuntu" option) fail (see picture below).

The error stack involves several lines and starts with

```
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOPIC[0] not in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : No southbridge IOAPIC found
AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
inittramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
Failed to execute/init (error -2)
...
```

The motherboard I am using is a MSI A88X-G41. I have already tried several hard drives and verified that the OS-image I have downloaded just today is working on different machines.

I was wondering if someone already has had a similar problem during the installation of Ubuntu or any other Linux operating systems and if they have found a way to fix it. I am sorry for the poor image quality, and for not including the entire stack as plain text.

[image: error stack]

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1052023/ioapic0-not-in-ivrs-table

Comment: The actual and only problem is "initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed". Everything that follows is just an consequence of that. Try different USB ports and, just to test, different Linux distributions.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Thank you for the input, unfortunately I was not able to resolve the issue during the installation, I will try however to fix it now that the OS is running

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for pointing me to the correct problem. I had tried changing the USB port and OS several times before, but after researching the issue pointed out by you, I finally found a solution, however by mere luck.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question do _answer_ it. Not in the question, but below. You can then accept the answer after a day or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by using *balenaEtcher* (https://www.balena.io/etcher/) instead of the standard Ubuntu *Startup Disk Creator*. The error stack regarding the IVRS table persisted, but the `inittramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed` disappeared and I was able to successfully install the operating systems.